# Go Lang - Gin : How to extract only the body (and ignore other garbage) from httputil.DumpRequest

Tags: go

I know that you can get the body content from

```
ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
```

But using httputil.DumpRequest

`dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(c.Request, true)`

will give the body contents along with other  values, the body content in the end.

> Content type: application/json IP: 127.0.0.1:36846 header token:  Content length: 76 Request Method: POST Request URL: /signup Body: 
>   POST /signup HTTP/1.1
>   Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36
>   {"fname":"aFirstName", "lname":"aLName", "email":"test@test.com", "password":"123"}

Is there an efficient way I can get only the body content from httputil.DumpRequest()? i.e In this case only

> {"fname":"aFirstName", "lname":"aLName", "email":"test@test.com", "password":"123"}

Comment: If the answer to your previous question is not correct don't duplicate the question but comment on the answer there and/or edit the question.

Comment: This is [an X/Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you're asking how to do Y (muck with the output of a debugging function) when you should be doing X (duplicating an `io.ReadCloser`). The answer to this question is "you don't".

Comment: @dave-c, I don't see this as a duplicate as the other question was how to "retain" the body.  Here I am trying to ignore the garbage and extract only what I need. I am a beginner in Go. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Very strictly speaking it isn't a duplicate; however this question only exists because of a poor answer to the other question (and close reasons are limited). It is not something that anyone should do. Don't use a debug function that isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `httputil.DumpRequest` for that, that's a debug function.

Assuming you want to parse json you can do something like this:

```
defer c.Request.Body.Close()
var data yourDataType
if err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
// handle data
```